# How can I turn off Visual Studio auto-formatting for a specific file type?

Tags: visual-studio, mustache

We use Mustache templates as part of a C#.Net and Javascript web app and Visual Studio has a nasty habit of re-formatting them and messing up tags.

For example, VS will turn this..

```
{{/Name}}
```

into...

```
{{ /> Name}}
```

...or change uppercase tags into lowercase tags which breaks the parser.

Is there any way to switch off VS auto-formatting for a specific file type (in our case files with extension .mustache)?

Comment: Somebody needs to create a language service so VS handles these files properly.  That could be you, the usual way that open source works.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was hoping more for a simple exclude, rather than having to do any extra work.  I'm not short of work to do :)

Comment: @HansPassant - I'd be willing to work on this exact thing because working with mustache templates in VS is driving me crazy - but every search I've tried leads me to something called 'VS Code' - can you point me to documentation on how to extend Visual Studio to highlight/autoformat a new language/filetype?